# How can I use the Options pattern (IOptions) with Azure Functions Premium? (it does not allow colons in app setting names)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

**Summary:**
I would like to use the [Options Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#working-with-options-and-settings) with Azure Functions Premium, but to do so I need to put app settings in the format:

```
"Values": {
    "MyOptions:MyCustomSetting": "Foobar"
}
```

But it seems that Azure Functions premium does not allow colons ":" in app setting names.

Is the Options pattern possible in Azure Functions premium?

**More detail:**

I recently migrated an app from a consumption plan to a premium plan. To do this I deleted and recreated the function app, but the deployment failed with an error:

```
AppSetting with name 'OidcApiAuthSettings:Audience' is not allowed
```

In the consumption plan version of my app, I have a bunch of settings using this format in order to follow the Options pattern for strongly typed configuration.

I checked through the portal, and sure enough, in a consumption plan I can create settings in this format, but in a premium plan I get a message: *"App setting names can only contain letters, numbers (0-9), periods ("."), and underscores ("_")"*

Comment: When you are talking about "deployment", how is deployed your Function App? From the portal? From IaC  Where are these settings defined? I am just trying to understand the context. Indeed there is no reason why you could not have settings with ":" as environment variables.

Do you have the message "App setting names can only contain letters, numbers (0-9), periods ("."), and underscores ("_")" when you are manually creating a setting in the Configuration tab of your Premium Function App in the Azure portal?

Comment: Thanks @TechWatching. the message "AppSetting with name 'OidcApiAuthSettings:Audience' is not allowed" occurs when deploying a Bicep template with the az cli (through Azure Pipelines.

The message "App setting names can only contain letters, numbers (0-9), periods ("."), and underscores ("_")" appears when trying to manually set the app setting through the portal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use double underscore to replace colons:

```
'OidcApiAuthSettings__Audience'
```